# use group and distinct in one sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to have a query that shows PCOUNTRY with a count of DISTINCT (ACTARRVDATE) for each PCOUNTRY value. I am trying below query

```
SELECT  
    pcountry, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN orde_.actarrvdate is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS actarrvdate
FROM    
    orde_  
WHERE 
    orde_.CANCELLED = 0
    and orde_.CLIENTNUM in ('ENAWC', 'ENAWB')
    AND  ((CONVERT(varchar(8),ACTARRVDATE,112)) BETWEEN  '20160201' AND '20160228')
    AND PCOUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND PCOUNTRY <> ''

GROUP BY 
    pcountry,actarrvdate 
 ORDER BY   pcountry
```

The result is coming

```
pcountry     actarrvdate
201114       1
201114       0
537456       0
```

how can i create this query . Thanks for your precious time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct query would look like:

```
SELECT pcountry, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT orde_.actarrvdate ) AS actarrvdate
FROM orde_  
WHERE orde_.CANCELLED = 0 AND
      orde_.CLIENTNUM in ('ENAWC', 'ENAWB') AND
      ACTARRVDATE >= '20160201' AND
      ACTARRVDATE < DATEADD(day, 1, '20160228') AND
      PCOUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND PCOUNTRY <> ''
GROUP BY pcountry
ORDER BY pcountry
```

Notes:

- The proper expression is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.
- The column does not go into the `GROUP BY`.
- Do date/time comparisons using date/time types.  Don't convert to strings.
- `between` can be dangerous in SQL, because of the hidden time component (your original logic is fine if there is no time component, but it can be a dangerous habit).
- Do you realize that 2016 is a leap year, so the last day of February was 2016-02-29?

Comment: Should theoretically be +3, 1 for the correct query, 1 for pointing out how abhorrent converting dates to varchar is for comparison and giving a sargable alternative, and 3 for advising to avoid `BETWEEN`. Alas that isn't possible. Quick note though, SQL Server uses `DATEADD` rather than `DATE_ADD`, and `PCOUNTRY IS NOT NULL` is redundant, since `PCOUNTRY <> ''` will also eliminate null values, but that is only really an aesthetic change since it would be optimised away anyway.

Comment: @A.Goutam Yes, sorry i was referring to my upvote. It was a bit of tongue in cheek to give the answer the appropriate praise. It was not meant as an instruction or advise to anyone. I just meant that the importance of the additional changes Gordon has made should not be overlooked, as they can make a huge difference not only in terms of getting the results expected, but also in terms of query performance. I have seen queries reduced from minutes to milliseconds, simply by removing varchar conversions on dates.

Comment: @GarethD my last query was taking near 2.5 min with varchar but this query is taking 0.3 second this is very nice idea and i will keep in mind for need time

Comment: @GarethD you was taking about `PCOUNTRY IS NOT NULL is redundant`  but the pcountry can be  `' '` or NULL so how can i check in one statement :)

Comment: Do you want to exclude rows where `pcountry` is `' '` from the results? If so you could use `WHERE LEN(PCOUNTRY) > 0` - I am not sure there is a sargable method to remove empty strings with any number of spaces